# Does trigger(after insert) on table slow down inserting into this table

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have a big table(`bo_sip_cti_event`) which is too largest to even run queries on this so I made the same table (`bo_sip_cti_event_day`), added trigger after insert on `bo_sip_cti_event` to add all the same values to `bo_sip_cti_event_day` and now I am thinking if I significantly slowed down inserts into `bo_sip_cti_event`.

So generally, does trigger after insert slow down operations on this table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the trigger *must* slow down inserts.

The reason is that relational databases are [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) compliant: All actions, including side-effects like triggers, must be completed before the update transaction completes. So triggers must be executed synchronously, and that consumes CPU, and in your case I/O too, which ultimately takes more time. There's no getting around it.

Comment: So on every insert to bo_sip_cti_event I lose time to make insert to bo_sip_cti_event_day. Do I get it correct?

Comment: @Michu93 yes. When the initial insert execution completes, so too must the one inside the trigger. If the client making insert to the event table were to immediately follow it with a query on the day table, they will expect to see, and be guaranteed to see, new data in the day table.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes: it is additional overhead, so obviously it takes time to finish the transaction with the additional trigger execution.

Your design makes me wonder if:

- You explored all options to speed up your large table. Even billions of rows can be handled quite fine, if you have proper index ect. But it all depends on the table, the design, the data and the queries.
- What exactly your trigger is doing. The table name "_day" raises questions when and where and how exactly this table is cleaned out at midnight. Hopefully not inside the trigger function, and hopefully not with a "DELETE FROM".

Comment: It is table which contains all informations from telephony platform -freeswitch. I already have some indexes on columns which I use in SELECTS. No, no, I am not doing anything more than insert in trigger function but at night I run `DELETE FROM bo_sip_cti_event_day` but it seems to be fast, is there better way?